# Unable to display data from Firebase Realtime DataBase in antd Form

Tags: reactjs, antd

I'm trying to display data from firebase in an antd table using hooks. I created a mini version of this application with a simple bootstrap design pulling the data from firebase with:

```
   useEffect(() => {
    fireDB.child('leaderboard').on('value', snapshot=> {
      if (snapshot.val() !== null) {
        setLeaderBoardObjects({
          ...snapshot.val()
        });
      }
    })
  }, [])
```

and displaying it with:

```
            <tbody>
              {
                Object.keys(leaderBoardObjects).map(id => {
                  return <tr key={id}>
                      <td>{leaderBoardObjects[id].name}</td>
                      <td>{leaderBoardObjects[id].client}</td>
                      <td>{leaderBoardObjects[id].project}</td>
                      <td>{leaderBoardObjects[id].min_value}</td>
                      <td>{leaderBoardObjects[id].max_value}</td>
                      <td>
                        <a className="btn txt-primary" onClick={() => {setCurrentId(id)}}>
                          <i className="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i>
                        </a>
                        <a className="btn txt-danger" onClick={() => {onDelete(id)}}>
                          <i className="fas fa-trash"></i>
                        </a>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                })
              }
            </tbody>
```

mapping through each id.

antd is quite different in how their tables are designed and I can't seem to find the proper way to display the data.

I thought since the table for antd is called:

```
<Table
 columns={columns}
 dataSource={data}
/>
```

I should assign the `Object.keys().map` to data:

```
let data = Object.keys(leaderBoardObjects).map(dataIndex =>
 leaderBoardObjects[dataIndex].columns
);
```

I've tried a few variations this way, with and without `.columns`. I thought that would be necessary to specify the given column structure, but I don't think that really matters. Full code currently is:

```
const LeaderBoard = () => {
  let [leaderBoardObjects, setLeaderBoardObjects] = useState({});

 
   useEffect(() => {
    fireDB.child('leaderboard').on('value', snapshot=> {
      if (snapshot.val() !== null) {
        setLeaderBoardObjects({
          ...snapshot.val()
        });
      }
    })
  }, []) 

  let data = Object.keys(leaderBoardObjects).map(dataIndex => 
    leaderBoardObjects[dataIndex].columns
  ); 

  const columns = [
    {
      title: 'Name',
      dataIndex: 'name',
      sorter: true,
      render: name => `${name}`,
      width: '25%',
    },
    {
      title: 'Client',
      dataIndex: 'client',
      render: client => `${client}`,
      width: '25%',
    },
    {
      title: 'Project',
      dataIndex: 'project',
      render: project => `${project}`,
      width: '25%',
    },
    {
      title: 'Min Value',
      dataIndex: 'min_value',
      render: min_value => `${min_value}`,
      width: '10',
    },
    {
      title: 'Max Value',
      dataIndex: 'max_value',
      render: max_value => `${max_value}`,
      width: '15',
    }
  ];


  return (
    <Table
      columns={columns}
      dataSource={data} 
    />
  )
}

export default LeaderBoard
```

Which just displays `undefined` for each column.

Clearly overlooking or overcomplicating something, but have been stuck on this for longer than I'd like to admit.

EDIT: I have the dumb and answered my own question. I did not in fact try every variation with/without `.columns`.

```
  let data = Object.keys(leaderBoardObjects).map(dataIndex => 
    leaderBoardObjects[dataIndex]
  );
```

Works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the dumb and answered my own question. I did not in fact try every variation with/without `.columns`.

```
let data = Object.keys(leaderBoardObjects).map(dataIndex => 
   leaderBoardObjects[dataIndex]
 );
```

Works.